# Why does Danish have more short-long vowel pairs than Swedish?

Tags: phonology, vowels, evolution, danish

In Danish, the pair /ø/ and /ø:/ are distinguished from the pair /œ/ and /œ:/. In Swedish, the phonemes /ø:/ and /œ/ are treated as a short-long pair.

In Danish, the pair /ɔ/ and /ɔ:/ are distinguished from /o/ and /o:/. In Swedish, /o:/ and /ɔ/ are treated as a short-long pair.

How did Danish develop a length distinction for the qualities /o/, /ɔ/, /ø/, and /œ/?

Comment: I think you’re asking this the wrong way around – without looking up the developments specifically, I think it’s rather that Swedish _lost_ the distinction. Old Norse had both _ø/ǿ_ and _ǫ/ǫ́_ (later _ö/ö́_), as well as both _a/á_ (later _a/å_) and _o/ó_, with length later redistributed by syllable weight. Danish has /ø, øː/, /œ, œː/, /a, aː/, /ɔ, ɔː/ and /o, oː/; the only pair Swedish has is /a, aː/. Note that, much like English, Swedish has virtually no tense short vowels – only /e/ remains, and only in some dialects – so it’s not surprisingly that there are no /ø/ and /o/ phonemes.

Comment: So Swedish lost some pairs while Danish retained them?

Comment: It’s probably a bit more complicated than that, but essentially yes. Consider that historically, Danish /ɔː/ (written _å_) is equivalent to Swedish /oː/, while Danish /oː/ (written _o_) is equivalent to Swedish /uː/, and Danish /uː/ (written _u_) is equivalent to Swedish /ʉː/ – the phonemes don’t match up neatly, but it’s clear that Danish and Old Norse both have tense and lax short vowels, while Swedish (almost) only has lax ones, so by Occam’s Razor you’d assume that Swedish lost phonemes along the way.